# TClientDataSet : TStream to VarBinary

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, datasnap, dbexpress, tclientdataset

I am writing a REST Data Snap server and have to save a TStream to a VarBinary(384) field. I try to CreateBlobStream on the field but get exception errors when I attempt this.

How do one save to a VarBinary field using DBExpress?

```
with cdsInsertIssueActionTemplateDetail do
      begin
        Active := True;
        Insert();
        T11 := TMemoryStream.Create;
        DM.CopyStreamToMemoryStream(Template11, T11);
        BlobField := TBlobField(FieldByName('FingerTemplate'));
        BS := CreateBlobStream(BlobField, bmWrite); //Exception occurs here
        BS.CopyFrom(T11, T11.Size);
        T11.Free;
        BS.Free;
        Post();
        Active := False;
      end;
```

Comment: I have tried making use of the TSQLQuery parameters to write the field without any success.     T11 := TMemoryStream.Create;
                      DM.CopyStreamToMemoryStream(Template11, T11);
                      Params.ParamByName('FingerTemplate').DataType := ftBlob;
                          Params.ParamByName('FingerTemplate').LoadFromStream(Template11, ftBlob);     Receive a 'Stream read error' on this

Comment: Have you made sure that `FieldByName('FingerTemplate')` actually returns a `TBlobField`? You can use `FieldByName('FingerTemplate') as TBlobStream` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get it to work by making FingerTemplate a parameter in the TSQLQuery as follows:

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblIssueActionTemplateDetail]([ActionUID],[FingerTemplate] ,[FingerTemplateIndex] ,[FingerIndex] , [IsDuress],[AddedOnDateTime] ,[LastModifiedDateTime])
 VALUES (:ActionUID, :FingerTemplate, :FingertemplateIndex, :FingerIndex,0, :DateTime, :DateTime)

An made the Parameter's DataType of ftBlob

```
                begin
                  T21 := TMemoryStream.Create;
                  Template21.Position;
                  DM.CopyStreamToMemoryStream(Template21, T21);
                  BlobField := TBlobField(FieldByName('FingerTemplate'));
                   Params.ParamByName('FingerTemplate').SetBlobData(Template21, Template21.Size);
                  T21.Free;
                end;
```